# kSoap2 multipart/related response

Tags: java, android, xml, ksoap2, multipart

We have problems with getting a response from a webservice when we want to call it.
We are using the KSOAP2 Library and when we want to get normal SOAPObjects with Content-Type text/xml it all goes well but now we need to get a response from a action who gives back a content-type: multipart/related. So the standard code doesn't work.

```
public SoapObject getDocuments(String id, String type)
{

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_GETDOCUMENTS);
    Request.addProperty("humres", id);
    Request.addProperty("type", type);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 
    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GETDOCUMENTS, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        return response;        
    }
    catch(XmlPullParserException exPull)
    {
        exPull.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch(IOException exIO)
    {
        exIO.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And next up is the error we receive

```
    09-13 14:14:31.078: W/System.err(875): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: PI must not start with xml (position:unknown --=_1e3686ff8230e83d586a024e6feaaf4d
09-13 14:14:31.078: W/System.err(875): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
09-13 14:14:31.111: W/System.err(875): Content-Type: text/xml;
09-13 14:14:31.111: W/System.err(875):  charset=UTF-8
09-13 14:14:31.111: W/System.err(875): @6:5 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406386b8) 
09-13 14:14:31.111: W/System.err(875):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
09-13 14:14:31.118: W/System.err(875):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error(KXmlParser.java:269)
09-13 14:14:31.118: W/System.err(875):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseLegacy(KXmlParser.java:398)
09-13 14:14:31.118: W/System.err(875):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:366)
09-13 14:14:31.118: W/System.err(875):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1378)
09-13 14:14:31.118: W/System.err(875):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1408)
09-13 14:14:31.118: W/System.err(875):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
09-13 14:14:31.129: W/System.err(875):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
09-13 14:14:31.129: W/System.err(875):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:197)
09-13 14:14:31.129: W/System.err(875):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
09-13 14:14:31.129: W/System.err(875):  at com.cx.pservices.WebserviceUbPlus.getInvoice(WebserviceUbPlus.java:133)
09-13 14:14:31.129: W/System.err(875):  at com.cx.pservices.employer.facaturetab$Progress.doInBackground(facaturetab.java:346)
09-13 14:14:31.138: W/System.err(875):  at com.cx.pservices.employer.facaturetab$Progress.doInBackground(facaturetab.java:1)
09-13 14:14:31.148: W/System.err(875):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-13 14:14:31.148: W/System.err(875):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-13 14:14:31.158: W/System.err(875):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-13 14:14:31.158: W/System.err(875):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-13 14:14:31.158: W/System.err(875):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-13 14:14:31.158: W/System.err(875):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Response XML

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetInvoiceResponse xmlns:ns1="UBplusOnlineWebservice">
         <invoice xsi:type="xsd:string">
            <resultxml>
               <statuscode>100</statuscode>
               <message>
                  <Invoice>
                     <DocumentId>05-000053</DocumentId>
                     <Amount>36.89</Amount>
                     <Date>2012-09-06 00:00:00</Date>
                     <Description>Factuur 22050003</Description>
                  </Invoice>
               </message>
               <attachments>1</attachments>
               <filenames>
                  <filename>05-000053-05-22050003.pdf</filename>
               </filenames>
            </resultxml>
         </invoice>
      </ns1:GetInvoiceResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Maybe its good to know the raw what we except

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2012 11:56:44 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: cisession=WDRVaFAxC2MAKAF1VjtbMw9sWjNUIgMnCDZXd1hzB2hYYwdkBgsFbl00AidQPwQlBG0GMlE0Xj1XJgZlVTJXYQ03UTUAO1E2UzYCPFRjBD5YM1VnUGcLPQBmAWRWY1s3D25aMFRmA2MIMVc9WGEHN1hpBzMGZAVhXWICJ1A%2FBCUEbQYwUTZePVcmBjxVcVdfDTdRZgA8USVTYgJ8VHUEJFhuVSFQPgtoAGEBPFYjWzUPa1onVDEDYghhVypYNgcyWCIHPgZtBSVdawJ2UD4EZwRnBjtRJF5yV3cGMFVzV18NN1FlAD1ROVNzAi1UPQR1WG9VYVAwC2MAcQFHVnFbYw8%2FWmFUZQN5CBtXcFh0B3FYTwdmBj0FYl0%2BAnFQKwRiBHkGMFEoXjZXJAZ9VWtXYQ0gUWMAeFFmUykCOlQvBCRYblUhUD4LaABgATxWI1tuDz1aelR0AwsIMldnWHQHaFh6B2MGIAV%2BXXICPlBtBGwEZgYyUTJeMFcxBmZVNlc0DWZRNgBjUSRTPQI2VDwEJFggVSFQYQsrAAwBYlZgW3YPPVorVDsDJwhpVzRYOgcjWC4HMQYp; path=/; domain=.ubplusonline.nl
Set-Cookie: cisession=C2dRbFc3C2NReVImAG1dNQZlWjNcKlVxCDZXdwArBGtWbQJhVVgCaQtiACVVOgorBG0PO1YzC2hVJFU2UDdQZg03UTUDOABnVDEEOlBnUmgLYFFjV2ALPVE3UjcANV0xBmdaMFxuVTUIMVc9ADkENFZnAjZVNwJmCzQAJVU6CisEbQ85VjELaFUkVW9QdFBYDTdRZgM%2FAHRUZQR6UHFScgs9USVXOQtoUTBSbwB1XTMGYlonXDlVNAhhVyoAbgQxViwCO1U%2BAiILPQB0VTsKaQRnDzJWIwsnVXVVY1B2UFgNN1FlAz4AaFR0BCtQOVIjCzxRZVc3C2NRIFIUACddZQY2WmFcbVUvCBtXcAAsBHJWQQJjVW4CZQtoAHNVLgpsBHkPOVYvC2NVJlUuUG5QZg0gUWMDewA3VC4EPFArUnILPVElVzkLaFExUm8AdV1oBjRaelx8VV0IMldnACwEa1Z0AmZVcwJ5CyQAPFVoCmIEZg87VjULZVUzVTVQM1AzDWZRNgNgAHs%3D; path=/; domain=.ubplusonline.nl
X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.3)
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3176
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml";  boundary="=_5f570f873903a0a03b45f977ae3c4a2f"

--=_5f570f873903a0a03b45f977ae3c4a2f
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/xml;
 charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetInvoiceResponse xmlns:ns1="UBplusOnlineWebservice"><invoice xsi:type="xsd:string"><resultxml>
  <statuscode>100</statuscode>
  <message>
    <Invoice>
      <DocumentId>05-000053</DocumentId>
      <Amount>36.89</Amount>
      <Date>2012-09-06 00:00:00</Date>
      <Description>Factuur 22050003</Description>
    </Invoice>
  </message>
  <attachments>1</attachments>
  <filenames>
    <filename>05-000053-05-22050003.pdf</filename>
  </filenames>
</resultxml></invoice></ns1:GetInvoiceResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--=_5f570f873903a0a03b45f977ae3c4a2f
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <cc9034cb2aa23a6357e46d8f45e682d5>
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 name=
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=
```

Anyone get an Idea how to fix this? Thnx anyway

Comment: Could you please give the WSDL of your response ?

Comment: Any progress yet? Netty suffers from the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171082/nettyresponse-ignores-multipart-content-type